# Is their a way for changing OpenShift master/worker nodes IP address on a production cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

we want to change OpenShift master/worker nodes IP address on a production cluster.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the node and recreate it with the correct IP

For master nodes, you must first remove the`"etcd"`instance running on the node you will delete from the etcd quorum, before deleting the node

Do it one node at a time for the 3 masters nodes

The high level procedure is described here: https://docs.okd.io/4.12/backup_and_restore/control_plane_backup_and_restore/replacing-unhealthy-etcd-member.html